# Is there a way in TinyMCE 4 to automatically append a character while editing?

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

This is an issue in TinyMCE 4.3.13, new since TinyMCE 4.1.3. In our app, we have forced_root_block set to false. When an image is the last element on the page, if you try to delete it you get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null", unless it's the only element on the page.

If you wrap it in another element you don't get this error, and the image deletes. If there's any other item after the image, even a single character, you don't get the error and the image deletes.

So for example if you open the source and put this in:

```
a <img src="http://ridgeaviation.ie/images/czaw-SportsCruiser-pic01.jpg"/>
b
```

you can then delete the image from the UI.

But with this:

```
a <img src="http://ridgeaviation.ie/images/czaw-SportsCruiser-pic01.jpg"/>
```

you can't.

If you put " " at the end, you won't be able to delete because the editor apparently trims the space, But if you put "‌" at the end it doesn't get trimmed, is invisible, and you can delete the image.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',    toolbar: "fontselect fontsizeselect | bold italic underline| bullist numlist outdent indent | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | forecolor backcolor | link  anchor code",
    menubar: "edit insert view format table tools",
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
  ],
  image_advtab: true,
force_br_newlines: true,
force_p_newlines: false,
forced_root_block: false
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Easy (and free!) You should check out our premium features.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

So the question is, is there some way to auto-append "‌" to the text being edited, even after editing with Tools->Source Code? TinyMCE 3.x had cleanup_callback, but that's not available in 4.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use the TinyMCE `change` event and look for your special character at the end and if its not there add it?

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    ...
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            console.log('Content changed to:  ' + editor.getContent());
            //Check the content here and add your character to the end if needed
        });
    }
})
```

Here is a fiddle of how to use the `change` event...
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/q0faab

Comment: Yes, thanks! I used editor.on('NodeChange'), and it works great.